# Removing trend by performing differencing in Time series prediction

Tags: time-series, prediction, difference, trend

On the basis of literature, for temporal correlation modeling the trend should be removed from the time-series data. We choose differencing for removing the trend.

I would like to know:

When we perform the differencing the data completely change and subsequently the predictions will be changed.
For example, if we suppose the range of data is 7.9, 7.25, 6.98 and ..., then after performing the differencing the predictions will be below the 1. 
How should we assess the predictions in real world data?
Should we perform the similar differencing on a reference data, too?

I am using AR(p) temporal model. Additionally, the process is implemented in R software.

[Data sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7p7ay2z6wxumndr/all25.csv) (rn25_29_o):

```
class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("ambtemp", "dt"), row.names = c(NA, 
486L), class = "data.frame")

  ambtemp                  dt
1   -1.96 2007-09-28 23:55:00
2   -2.02 2007-09-28 23:57:00
3   -1.92 2007-09-28 23:59:00
4   -1.64 2007-09-29 00:01:00
5   -1.76 2007-09-29 00:03:00
6   -1.83 2007-09-29 00:05:00
```

---

```
dput(Dif_Median_ambtemp) 
structure(c(NA, 0.2, 0.16, -0.0700000000000001, -0.1, -0.04, 
-0.01, 0, 0.0700000000000001, 0.23, 0.16, -0.26, -0.3, -0.18, 
0, -0.04, -0.04, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, -0.02, -0.0999999999999999, 
0, 0.16, 0.0900000000000001, 0.28, 0.27, -0.17, -0.17, 0, -0.02, 
-0.12, -0.1, 0, -0.05, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0699999999999998, 
0, 0.03, -0.00999999999999979, 0, 0.0999999999999999, 0.0999999999999999, 
0.0800000000000001, 0.12, 0.24, 0.26, 0.0999999999999999, 0.0599999999999998, 
0.02, 0, -0.02, -0.0599999999999998, -0.0399999999999998, 0, 
0, -0.02, -0.0700000000000001, -0.24, -0.37, -0.22, -0.0799999999999998, 
-0.03, -0.12, -0.03, 0.1, 0.02, 0.14, 0.18, 0.0600000000000001, 
0, -0.02, -0.0600000000000001, -0.04, 0, -0.02, -0.0999999999999999, 
-0.11, -0.16, -0.13, 0.0800000000000001, 0.0800000000000001, 
0, 0.01, 0.12, 0, 0.22, 0.23, -0.1, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
0, 0, 0.02, 0.28, 0.3, 0.04, -0.0900000000000001, -0.0900000000000001, 
-0.01, -0.22, -0.37, -0.16, 0, -0.32, -0.45, -0.13, 0.04, 0.04, 
0, 0.1, 0.12, 0.0399999999999996, 0, 0, -0.12, 0, 0.14, 0.02, 
0, 0.02, 0.34, 0.3, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0900000000000001, 
-0.01, -0.01, -0.12, -0.11, 0, -0.17, -0.17, -0.16, -0.16, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.0900000000000003, 0.0900000000000003, 0, 0.11, 0.41, 
0.45, 0.27, 0, -0.15, -0.03, 0.0600000000000001, 0.0800000000000001, 
0.0600000000000001, 0.04, 0, -0.04, -0.0600000000000001, -0.14, 
-0.18, -0.0600000000000001, -0.01, -0.26, -0.32, -0.22, -0.15, 
0.12, 0.18, 0.0600000000000001, 0, 0.0800000000000001, 0, -0.11, 
-0.0299999999999998, 0.2, 0.33, 0.13, 0.0600000000000001, 0.0600000000000001, 
-0.01, -0.03, -0.15, -0.15, -0.0799999999999998, -0.0899999999999999, 
-0.04, -0.01, -0.01, -0.0600000000000001, -0.05, 0, 0.02, 0.05, 
0.18, 0.17, 0.05, 0.0800000000000001, 0.0600000000000001, 0.3, 
0.34, 0.0499999999999998, 0.02, 0.05, 0.03, -0.23, -0.48, -0.33, 
-0.13, -0.14, -0.11, -0.02, 0.04, 0.0800000000000001, 0.0800000000000001, 
0.13, 0.15, 0.0700000000000001, 0.01, -0.02, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.04, -0.0799999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.04, -0.03, -0.04, -0.0600000000000001, -0.02, 0.02, 0.04, 
0.04, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0.02, 0.0399999999999998, 
0.0199999999999998, 0, 0.14, 0.31, 0.19, 0.02, -0.01, -0.0700000000000001, 
-0.23, -0.2, -0.03, 0, -0.0799999999999998, -0.0799999999999998, 
0.44, 0.54, 0.0999999999999999, 0.1, 0.1, 0.26, 0.26, 0, 1.08, 
1.08, -0.24, -0.62, -0.44, -0.18, -0.02, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.16, 0.55, 
0.3, 0.26, 0.18, 0.18, 0.26, 0, -0.37, -0.37, 0.18, 0.41, 0.35, 
0.12, -0.73, -0.73, 0.07, 0.23, 0.16, -0.26, -0.26, 0.4, 0.4, 
0, 0.08, 1.1, 1.02, -0.27, -0.62, -0.84, -0.49, 0.19, 1.29, 1.12, 
0.62, 0.76, 0.48, 0.32, -0.82, -0.92, -0.17, -0.19, -0.33, -0.21, 
0, 0, 0.44, 0.98, 0.65, 0.11, -0.13, -0.13, -0.44, -0.89, -0.45, 
0.17, 0.17, 0.38, 0.4, 0.3, 0.16, 0, 0.5, 0.38, -0.22, -0.72, 
-0.65, 0, 0.38, 0.23, 0.0900000000000001, 0.25, 0.16, 0.66, 0.66, 
0, -1.09, -1.09, 0.17, 0.91, 0.8, 0.0599999999999996, 0, -0.21, 
-0.21, -0.0299999999999998, -0.0299999999999998, 0.16, 0.58, 
0.42, 0.62, 0.66, 0.0399999999999996, -0.96, -0.96, 0, 0, -0.04, 
-0.04, 0.71, 0.71, -0.27, -0.27, -0.54, 0.91, 1.44, 0.0599999999999996, 
0, -0.19, -0.379999999999999, -0.26, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, 
0.28, 0.45, 0, -0.22, -0.0499999999999998, 0.37, 0.57, 0.600000000000001, 
0, -0.95, -0.55, 0.21, 1.16, 0.04, -0.510000000000001, 0.0800000000000001, 
-0.22, 0.0999999999999996, 0.29, 0.29, -0.84, -0.84, 0.82, 0.87, 
0.0499999999999998, -0.34, -0.34, 0.0599999999999996, 0.0699999999999994, 
0.00999999999999979, 0, 0.31, 0.220000000000001, -0.0899999999999999, 
0, 0.199999999999999, 0.43, 0.23, -0.12, -0.12, -0.0199999999999996, 
-0.0199999999999996, 0, 0.52, 0.52, -0.44, -0.44, -0.0700000000000003, 
0.38, -0.29, -0.590000000000001, 0.149999999999999, 0, -0.34, 
-0.34, 0.350000000000001, 0.4, 0.0499999999999998, 0, 0.0700000000000003, 
0.0700000000000003, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
0, 0.0800000000000001, 0.66, 0.58, 0, 0.0499999999999998, 0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0300000000000002, -0.0300000000000002, -0.17, -0.42, -0.42, 
-0.37, -0.2, -0.13, 0.04, 0.17, 0.64, 0.71, 0.2, 0.13, 0.17, 
-0.51, -0.399999999999999, 0, 0, 0.26, -0.0200000000000005, 0, 
0.44, 0.75, 0.31, 0, -0.3, -0.3, 0, 0.00999999999999979, 0.00999999999999979, 
NA), .Dim = c(484L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "ambtemp"))
```

---

```
dput(x.fore)
structure(list(pred = structure(c(5.77898604276542, 5.76851499635615, 
5.75806783191914, 5.74764449498526, 5.73724493120963), .Tsp = c(487, 
491, 1), class = "ts"), se = structure(c(0.32761784341869, 0.40079130692622, 
0.46226728095271, 0.516242830302498, 0.564873114585049), .Tsp = c(487, 
491, 1), class = "ts")), .Names = c("pred", "se"))
```

Code:

```
require(zoo)
require(xts)
n= 3

ambtemp <-  subset(rn25_29_o, select=c("ambtemp")) # creating subset which includes only "ambtemp" column
Median_ambtemp <- rollmedian(ambtemp,n,fill = list(NA, NULL, NA)) # smoothing the data

Dif_Median_ambtemp <- diff(Median_ambtemp, 2)

te = (x.fit = arima(Dif_Median_ambtemp, order = c(1, 0, 0)))   # fit the model and print the results
x.fore = predict(te, n.ahead=5)
```

Comment: Yes, you should adjust the predictions if you work with the differenced data. It would be easier to give you further details if you add this information to the post: Which kind of model are you using, ARIMA time series models? Which software are you using? Can you post some sample data?

Comment: @javlacalle The question is amended. How should I adjust the predictions?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a replicable example (which package should I load to use `rollmedian`, what is the value of `n`? it is better to post the output of `dput(rn25_29_o)` so that we don't need to guess the structure of the data? Anyway, looking at the code I see that the following should adjust the forecasts to have the same level as `Median_ambtemp`:

```
diffinv(x.fore$pred, lag = 2, xi = tail(Dif_Median_ambtemp, 2))
```

Comment: `xi` should contain the last values of the observed series, in particular, as many as the lag order that you used when differencing the data (the same order that is used to do the inverse of the differencing filter). In this case the lag is 2, so `xi` contains the last two values of the series.

Comment: I encounter an error while running the code:                             Error in diffinv.vector(x, lag, differences, xi) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)

Comment: As I said I cannot reproduce your example. You could post the output of `dput(Dif_Median_ambtemp)` and `dput(x.fore)`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get that error but as the last value in `Dif_Median_ambtemp` is not available (`NA`) some of the forecasts are `NA` as well. I would recommend you to fit the model for `Dif_Median_ambtemp` without including the last observation, `Dif_Median_ambtemp[1:483]`. In that case, the forecasts that I get after applying `diffinv` are: `0.0100 0.0100 0.0310 0.0366 0.0604 0.0674 0.0919`.

Comment: I could also correct the code. I got the same results of reversed predictions as you mentioned. However, the predictions should be around: 5.652297, 5.605061, 5.558288, 5.511974, 5.466113.

Comment: You can downloud also the entire data.

Comment: Why should they be around those specific values? The forecasts should be around the last values observed in `Dif_Median_ambtemp`, which are the data to which you are fitting an AR(1) model.

Comment: The latest values of the original data are around 5 as you may see in the data sample hyperlink. The differenced predictions should be around 1. But when we perform diffinv function they should be again inversed into around 5.

Comment: The last values that I see in the CSV file are `-3.7 -3.7 -3.68 -3.61 -3.78 -3.62` and the last values in `Dif_Median_ambtemp` are `-0.30 -0.30 0.00 0.01 0.01`. You smoothed the original data by applying a rolling median and they you take first differences on the smoothed series. Why do you expect that the inverse of the differencing filter will recover the level of the original data?

Comment: Shouldn't I expect such a predictions after, smoothing, differencing and inversion? I intend to evaluate the AR() model by using Leave-one-out Cross validation method. If I couldn't retrieve final predictions in a similar scale with original data, how I should evaluate the model.

Comment: The inverse of the differencing filter does not undo the smoothing based on the rolling median. You could ask this last question in a new post, [stats.stackexchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) may be a more suitable place to make this question, which is more related to statistics rather than programming.

Comment: But rolling median, doesn't change the data. It does smooth the data.